# Specify Android Lint version

Tags: android, lint

How do I specify the version used for Android Lint? From the lint report: `<issues format="5" by="lint 3.5.3">`

Comment: lint is a static code analysis tool, It should be used with latest version. There is no such configuration in `lint.xml` to provide the linter version code.

Answer (score 13):

`Lint` is a part of `ADT`(Android Development Tools) and more specifically it depends on the Android Gradle Plugin Version. You cannot change `Lint` version independently from `gradlePluginVersion`. When you change `gradlePluginVersion`, `Lint` version will be changed automatically to the corresponding one from current version of the plugin.

If you want to disable some checks or write your own rules you may check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint). Also you may create your own 'Lint' modules using `"com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:$lintApiVersion"`
and `"com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:$lintApiVersion"` compileOnly dependencies from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-api?repo=google)

Hope it helps

Comment: Brilliant answer! The only thing I can add is if you don't know how to pick lint version for your rule, check out https://vadzimv.dev/2021/07/28/calculate-lint-version.html